# Is mating between human and non-human primates theoretically possible?

Tags: reproduction, genomics

I wonder if it is theoretically achievable to produce living offspring between a human and a non-human primate. Great apes have 24 pairs of chromosomes compared to our 23, however, it is known that a mule is made from a donkey (62 chromosomes) and a horse (64  chromosomes).
Are there other reasons why this human/non-human primate hybrid can't survive?

Comment: I don't know if it is theoretically possible (I guess yes), but there have been actual experimental attempts to do so, that all failed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanzee